# Is eating from a sandwich van which serves non-halal food okay?

Tags: halal-haram, food

I work in an office, where there is few sandwich or burger vans serving food. They have stored everything, so it is just matter of frying over stove, but the utensils touch that spam, port sausages etc. I had once egg burger from that lady and it was after that i released about the utensils being used to pick up sausages etc to put on burger, will affect my food. 
With that case, is that egg burger halal or haram?

Answer (score 2):

Carrion and Swine are *Najis* <sup>[6:145](https://quran.com/6/145?translations=84)</sup>, so you should not eat in the same utensils where they have made contact, and if you have no other choice you should wash them first.

> عن أبي ثعلبة الخشني أنه سأل رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال إنا نجاور أهل الكتاب وهم يطبخون في قدورهم الخنزير ويشربون في آنيتهم الخمر فقال رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم إن وجدتم غيرها فكلوا فيها واشربوا وإن لم تجدوا غيرها فارحضوها بالماء وكلوا واشربوا
>
> Abu Tha’labah al-khushani said that he asked the Messenger of Allah(ﷺ):
>
> "We live in the neighbourhood of the People of the Book and they cook in their pots(the flesh of) swine and drink wine in their vessels."
>
> The Messenger of Allah(ﷺ) said: "If you find any other pots, then eat in them and drink. But if you do not find any others, then wash them with water and eat and drink (In them)."
>
> <sup>— [Abu Daud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/28/104); also recorded by [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/72/14) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/34/12) etc.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure<sup>*</sup> that haram substance did make it to your food as a result of the same utensil touching your food then it definitely is haram.

<sup>*</sup>

1. Are you absolutely confident, so much so that you could swear by the sanctity of the Holy Quran about it, that the same utensil was used without it being washed prior to touching your food? If yes then it's haram.
2. Is there room for doubt that different or clean utensil was used to prepare your food? If yes, then it is halal.